# Simple javascript IF statement - what is the correct syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax, if-statement, statements

Suppose I have this URL:

```
www.example.com/product-p/xxx.htm
```

The following javascript code picks out the phrase `product-p` from the URL:

```
urlPath = window.location.pathname; 
urlPathArray = urlPath.split('/'); 
urlPath1 = urlPathArray[urlPathArray.length - 2];
```

I can then use document.write to display the phrase `product-p`:

```
document.write(''+urlPath1+'')
```

My question is...

How do I create an IF statement such that if urlPath1 = 'product-p' then document.write (something), else document.write (blank)?

I have tried to do this but my syntax is probably wrong (I'm not too good at JS).

I initially thought the code would be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
urlPath=window.location.pathname; 
urlPathArray = urlPath.split('/'); 
urlPath1 = urlPathArray[urlPathArray.length - 2]; 

if (urlPath1 = "product-p"){
    document.write('test'); 
}
else {
    document.write(''); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (urlPath1 = "product-p")
//           ^ single = is assignment
```

Should be:

```
if (urlPath1 == "product-p")
//           ^ double == is comparison
```

---

Note that:

```
document.write(''+urlPath1+'')
```

Should be simply:

```
document.write(urlPath1)
```

You're concating the `urlpath` string with two empty strings... it doesn't do much.

Comment: Doh! Thanks very much for this - On that note I think its time to get some shut-eye!

Comment: @user1438551. Don't worry things like that happens. Had you tested your code with jsLint it would have told you that mistake. Good night warrior.

Comment: Thanks for the tip gdoron, I'll be sure to use jsLint in future. I'll also simplify (''.+urlPath1+'') as described. Take care!